how do i set a custom emote as a booster role icon like bleed has it discord.py
im trying to set a custom booster role icon so the way i have it is it steals the emote then sets it as the icon then deletes it but it wont work
i tried everything i even had gpt helping me but it was not working idk what to do im trying to have it so when i do .bri role name :custom emote: it will steal the emote set it as a icon for the role then delete it or i can do it anyway u guys know that works please help me i am losing my mind!
async def bri(ctx, role_name: str, emoji: discord.PartialEmoji):
    # Check if the emoji is valid
    if not isinstance(emoji, discord.PartialEmoji):
        await ctx.send("You can only use custom emojis for this command.")
        return

    # Find the role by name
    booster_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)

    if not booster_role:
        await ctx.send("Could not find the specified role.")
        return

    try:
        # Fetch the image data of the emoji
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(str(emoji.url)) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    emoji_image = await response.read()
                else:
                    raise discord.HTTPException(f"Failed to fetch emoji image. Status code: {response.status}")

        # Add the emoji to the current guild
        stolen_emoji = await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=emoji.name, image=emoji_image)

        # Inform the user that the emoji has been created
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully created the emoji {stolen_emoji} and cannot set it as role icon, but you can use it for visual representation!")

        # Optionally: Delete the emoji if you want to remove it after notifying
        await stolen_emoji.delete()

    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Error: {str(e)}")

# Error handling for permissions or other issues
@bri.error
async def bri_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to manage roles or emojis.")
    else:
        # Print and send any other errors
        print(f"Error: {error}")
        await ctx.send(f"An error occurred: {error}")



Making a bot take custom emote is only possible if the same bot is in the server where the emoji came from
